# Issue with modifying size of varchar

Tags: mysql, sql

When I try to modify size of `varchar`:

```
alter table foo modify column content varchar(20000);
```

I got this error:

```
ERROR 1118 (42000): Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, 
not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. 
You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs
```

How to use `varchar` with large data ?

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  It seems quite clear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff How to use varchar with large data ?

Comment: . . Use `text`:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html.

Comment: You can use TEXT datatype it has large size it depends on your OS file system.

Answer (score 0):

Youssef, I think you're getting confused between varchar size and row size. A varchar can be up to 65533 in length (2 bytes are reserved to define the length) so your varchar is within the accepted size, however the other columns in your table must add up to more than 45535 bytes - thus giving you a "row" size error.

If you post your existing create table script we can confirm that this is the case.

The pertinent section in the manual is [C.10.4  Limits on Table Column Count and Row Size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html)